# Render view instead of partial from turbo stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

I have a Rails controller action that shares a common view with other actions:

```
def foo
  # do foo things
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :baz }
    format.turbo_stream { render :baz }
  end
end
```

I'm looking to render the complete `baz` view (i.e. **not** a partial) from `foo.turbo_stream.erb`. Is there a way to tell turbo streams "Use this view," instead of a partial?

I am otherwise looking at shoving the entirety of the view into `_baz.html.erb`, and then making a one-line render call to the partial-thats-actually-everything in `baz.html.erb`.

```
# app/views/[controller]/_baz.html.erb
<!-- full view contents here --> 


# app/views/[controller]/baz.html.erb
<%= render :baz %>
```

…which I can do, and does work, but just feels janky and wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` in controllers defaults to rendering a template. `render` in views defaults to partial. Partial is a template with an underscore:

```rb
# from controller
render "baz"                      # renders "controller/baz"
render template: "controller/baz"

render "_baz"                     # renders "controller/_baz"
render partial: "baz"
render template: "controller/_baz"
```

```rb
# from view
render "baz"                      # renders "controller/_baz"
render partial: "baz"

render template: "controller/baz" # renders "controller/baz"
```

---

As a side note, can't `turbo_frame_tag` solve this particular situation? just wrap everything with the same frame and you don't need turbo_stream.

Rendering a template that actually belongs to some other controller action can work but it does get a little iffy and could be a bit brittle when making changes. I've seen `index.html.erb` and `_index.html.erb` or `show.html.erb` and `_show.html.erb` to be a pattern. Template `index` for the concrete controller action. Partial `_index` for the reusable bit that can be rendered from other templates, and more importantly is expected to be reusable because it's a partial.

Comment: The `:template` keyword in the options has is what I was looking for, thanks!